# Why isn't there Electronics careers page?

Tags: discussion, support

After seeing this question [Why isn't there a UX.SE Careers page?](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1841/40298)

I got this question that why SE isn't providing careers for Electronic professionals?

or did I miss it?

Comment: I think the same answer applies here, adding that probably the site is not large enough yet.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question as to why there's no direct link / categories, but you can link a Careers profile here: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3340/why-electrical-engineering-account-cant-be-attached-to-careers-2-0-account

Comment: earlier thread with an identical question: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3808/sub-beta-site-to-eese

Comment: @clabacchio personally, I don't care whether the site is large or not. this Electronics field has equal opportunities as software field jobs. and also all the professionals around the world can be found here. It will be great if Electronics also has a careers page..

Comment: I'm not saying it shouldn't be done, just that maybe someone thought it wouldn't have the same success as Stack Overflow's.  I guess it takes some time and investment to run a site like that, and maybe it's not yet worthy. I'm just speculating here.